# Hide components in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I am currently working on a django project and I would like to be able to hide some components in the form until the user triggers it. I decided to use the form manually and I have not been able to get the desired results.

Below is an image of the form in it simplest state

[image]

I would want the page to load with only **'First Name', 'Last Name' and 'Your Choice'** displaying and the choice of the user should trigger either **'Your Hostel' or 'Your City'** to pop up.

Below is the manual form

```
<form method="post" class="order-form">

{{ form.non_field_errors }}

<div id="first" class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.first_name.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}">First Name:</label>
    {{ form.first_name }}
</div>

<div id="last" class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.last_name.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}">Last Name:</label>
    {{ form.last_name }}
</div>

<div id="option" class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.delivery_option.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.delivery_option.id_for_label }}">Your Choice:</label>
    {{ form.delivery_option }}
</div>


<div id="hostle" class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.hostel.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.hostel.id_for_label }}">Your Hostel:</label>
    {{ form.hostel }}
</div>


<div id="city" class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.city.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.city.id_for_label }}">Your City:</label>
    {{ form.city }}
</div>
```

Can someone kindly help me. I'm new to this environment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set some of the divs to `hidden` and then use Javascript to change it once the user picks an option.

Comment: I tried with this script but it didn't work `<script>
$("#option").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Campus") {
    $('#hostle').show();
    $('#city').hide();
    $('#hostle').attr('required', '');
    
  } else {
    $('#hostle').hide();
    $('#city').show();

});
$("#option").trigger("change");
</script> `